# AES Encryption with EasyCrypto C# and Decryption in C++ using Crypto++

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, .net-6.0, crypto++

I have encrypted a string using EasyCrypto in C# using the following code

Encryption C#:

```
/*
EasyCrypto encrypted key format from CryptoContainer.cs file from the EasyCrypto source on GitHub.

         *      Format:
         *          04 bytes    00  - MagicNumber
         *          02 bytes    04  - DataVersionNumber
         *          02 bytes    06  - MinCompatibleDataVersionNumber
         *          16 bytes    08  - IV
         *          32 bytes    24  - Salt
         *          19 bytes    56  - Key check value
         *          48 bytes    75  - MAC
         *          04 bytes   123  - Additional header data length
         *          xx bytes   127  - Additional data
         *          ----- end of header ----- (sum: 127)
         *          xx bytes     - additional header data (0 for version 1)
         *          xx bytes     - data
         */

AesEncryption.EncryptWithPassword("data to encrypt", "password string");

/*
Method Description:
Encrypts string and returns string. Salt and IV will be embedded to encrypted string. Can later be decrypted with 
EasyCrypto.AesEncryption.DecryptWithPassword(System.String,System.String,EasyCrypto.ReportAndCancellationToken) 
IV and salt are generated by EasyCrypto.CryptoRandom which is using System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes.
IV size is 16 bytes (128 bits) and key size will be 32 bytes (256 bits).
/*
```

I am trying to decrypt in C++ using Crypto++, using the following code. I am just getting the error "ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size", what is the missing part in the code? any help would be highly appreciable.

Decryption C++:

```
string Decrypt() {
    
// getting CryptoPP::byte array from passowrd
    string destination;
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss(<hex of password string>, true, new CryptoPP::HexDecoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(destination)));
    CryptoPP::byte* keyByteArray = (CryptoPP::byte*)destination.data();

// getting CryptoPP::byte array from encoded data
    string pkDst;
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss2(<hex of encoded data>, true, new CryptoPP::HexDecoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(pkDst)));
    CryptoPP::byte* pkByteArray = (CryptoPP::byte*)pkDst.data();

// getting initialization vector from encoded data
    CryptoPP::byte iv[16]; 
    for (int i = 8; i < 24; i++) {
        iv[i] = pkByteArray[i];
    }


    string result = CBCMode_Decrypt(keyByteArray, 32, iv);

    return result;
}


string CBCMode_Decrypt(CryptoPP::byte key[], int keySize, CryptoPP::byte iv[]) {
          string recovered = "";
          //Decryption
          try
          {
              CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption d;

              d.SetKeyWithIV(key, keySize, iv);
              // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
              //  padding as required.
              CryptoPP::StringSource s("encoded string", true, new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(d, new CryptoPP::StringSink(recovered))); // StringSource
          }
          catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
          {
              cerr << e.what() << endl;
              exit(1);
          }
          return recovered;
      }
```

Comment: The Crypto++ code seems to be missing the key derivation via PBKDF2. Also, it is misleading to name the decryption method `CFBMode_Decrypt()` when it uses CBC instead of CFB.

Comment: Thank you, I have very little or no knowledge of encryptions. I have no idea what is key derivation via PBKDF2. As far as CFB_Mode is concerned when I use CBC_Mode it gives block size error so I used CFB_Mode. I also have no idea which mode I have to use. Can you please help to get in the right direction! Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: I can show you the way: `AesEncryption.EncryptWithPassword(...)` returns the result Base64 encoded. This result contains several data, namely the ciphertext, an IV (16 bytes), a salt (32 bytes) and (probably) a MAC (HMACSHA384, 48 bytes). The first thing to do is to extract these parts from the result. In the [EasyCrypto](https://github.com/stanac/EasyCrypto) documentation I can't find any information about the format/structure of the result, i.e. if you can't find anything either, you would have to determine this information by a code analysis.

Comment: Once you have determined the parts, the 32 bytes key must first be derived using salt and password via PBKDF2. The library uses an iteration count of 25000 and (according to the description) the default hash of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` (which is SHA1). Crypto++ supports PBKDF2 with [`PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC). Then the ciphertext can be decrypted with AES-256 in CBC mode and PKCS#7 padding (using IV and key). The MAC (if any) is provided for authentication.

Comment: I got the format in CryptoContainer.cs file in EasyCrypto source, let me add to the question and I have the key that I have used for encryption in C#, I have generated the key myself.

Comment: According to the format and your useful information I have updated my code, but I am getting the error "ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Crypto++ code, the following steps must be performed for decryption:

- Base64 decoding of the EasyCrypto data
- Separating IV, salt and ciphertext (using the information from the CryptoContainer.cs file)
- Deriving the 32 bytes key via PBKDF2 using salt and password (digest: SHA-1, iteration count: 25000)
- Decryption with AES-256 in CBC mode and PKCS#7 padding (using key and IV)

A possible Crypto++ implementation is:

```c
#include "aes.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "pwdbased.h"
#include "sha.h"
#include "base64.h"

using namespace CryptoPP;
using namespace std;

...

// Base64 decode data from EasyCrypto
string encoded = "bqCrDAQABABtXsh2DxqYdpZc6M6+kGALOsKUHzxoMR6WAVg5Qtj3zWbr4MiEBdqt9nPIiIZAynFAZmweHQPa/PhEItR6M8Jg1bHAYeQ8Cm5eUlKNzPXFNfuUw0+qtds29S0L4wAWY0xfuiBJTUeTJuSLWqoirm/rHGOWAAAAAKtBivUDvxta1d0QXE6J9x5VdSpAw2LIlXARKzmz+JRDtJcaj4KmGmXW/1GjZlMiUA==";
string decoded;
StringSource ssB64(
    encoded, 
    true,
    new Base64Decoder(
        new StringSink(decoded)
    ) 
); 

// Separate IV, salt and ciphertext
string ivStr = decoded.substr(8, 16);
string saltStr = decoded.substr(24, 32);
string ciphertextStr = decoded.substr(127);

// Derive 32 bytes key using PBKDF2
char password[] = "my passphrase";
unsigned int iterations = 25000;
byte key[32];
size_t keyLen = sizeof(key);
PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<SHA1> pbkdf;
pbkdf.DeriveKey(key, keyLen, 0, (byte*)password, sizeof(password), (byte*)saltStr.c_str(), saltStr.length(), iterations, 0.0f);

// Decrypt with AES-256, CBC, PKCS#7 padding
string decrypted;
CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption decryption(key, keyLen, (byte*)ivStr.c_str());
StringSource ssDec(
    ciphertextStr,
    true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(
        decryption,
        new StringSink(decrypted),
        BlockPaddingSchemeDef::BlockPaddingScheme::PKCS_PADDING
    )
);

// Output
cout << "Decrypted: " << decrypted << "\n";
```

with the output:

```
Decrypted: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

The ciphertext was generated with EasyCrypto:

```cs
AesEncryption.EncryptWithPassword("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "my passphrase");
```

---

The previous section focused on decryption. Note, however, that for security reasons, authentication is required *before* decryption and decryption may only be performed on successfully authenticated data.
For authentication also the MAC must be determined in addition to IV, salt and ciphertext. EasyCrypto applies an HMAC-SHA-384 as MAC. Only the ciphertext is used to determine the MAC, and the key for authentication is the same as the key for encryption.
For authentication, the calculated and the sent MAC must be compared. If both are the same, the authentication is successful (and the decryption can be performed).

A possible Crypto++ implementation for the authentication is:

```c
// Get the sent MAC
string macSentStr = decoded.substr(75, 48);

// Calculate the MAC using ciphertext and encryption key
string macCalcStr;
HMAC<SHA384> hmac(key, keyLen);
StringSource ssMac(
    ciphertextStr, 
    true,
    new HashFilter(hmac,
        new StringSink(macCalcStr)
    )  
); 

// Compare both MACs
cout << (!macSentStr.compare(macCalcStr) ? "Authentication successful" : "Authentication failed") << endl; // compare returns 0 if both strings match
```

which successfully authenticates the sample data.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll test this implementation tommorow and will give you feedback once again thank you so much.

Comment: I was mixing key with password, I thought key is the password. Thank you for your time and effort.